# Choosing capacitors for QI charger

Tags: capacitor, wireless-charging

I plan on using the TI [BQ51051B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51051b.pdf) as a QI reciever and Li-po charger. I plan to use the TDK [WR121210-27M8-ID](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/wireless-charge/wireless-charge/rx-coil-module/catalog/wlc_rx_wr121210-27m8-id_en.pdf) as the receiving coil, and the TDK [WT151512-22F2-ID](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/wireless-charge/wireless-charge/tx-coil-module/catalog/wlc_tx_wt151512-22f2-id_en.pdf) as the transmitting coil.

I am having trouble determining the values of the series and parallel capacitors I need. The BQ51051B datasheet says:

[image: choosing capacitors]

The datasheet for the Rx Coil states that the inductance at 100 kHz and 1 V RMS is 8.32 μH:
[image: correct_inductance]

Is this the value of Ls or Ls'? How could I determine the value of the remaining variable? Is it OK to use this value for both Ls and Ls'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to my question.

In [this TI forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/1127044/bq51051b-confused-while-selecting-the-coil), a reply states:

> Ls' -- is a measurement of the RX coil L simulating the coil be on the TX, typically higher than Ls.

> Ls -- is a measurement of the RX coil L in free space, not on TX.

> For Ls=16uH with Ls'=17.6uH (estimate 10% increase)  C1 = 144nF C2 = 1600pF

This leads me to believe that the value in the datasheet is Ls, and to calculate Ls', I need to estimate a 10% increase from Ls, so:

$$L_S'=8.2\mu H*1.1=9.02\mu H$$

Then to find C1(series):

$$\frac{1}{(2\pi*100kHz)^2*9.02\mu H}=280.82nF$$

Then to find C2(parallel):

$$((1MHz*2\pi)^2*6.8\mu H-\frac{1}{280.82nF})^{-1}=3775pF$$

Do these values seem reasonable?

Comment: Related: fine tuning the circuits can make a substantial difference to power transfer,